# Highcharts: highlight selected/active button

Tags: highcharts

Chart has Linear and Logarithmic buttons. How to get the one which is active to be highlighted? Code below changes colour on hover only.

https://jsfiddle.net/stgk1mrx/

```
 navigation: {
        buttonOptions: {
            theme: {
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        fill: '#00f'
                    },
                    select: {
                        fill: '#f00'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myButton: {
                symbol: 'circle',
                symbolStrokeWidth: 1,
                symbolFill: '#bada55',
                symbolStroke: '#330033',


                onclick: function() {
                    // Something happens here
                    var self = this.exportSVGElements[2]; // 0-1 is first button, 2-3 is second button etc.
                    self.setState(2);
                    console.log('clicked!');
                },

                theme: {
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            fill: '#FF0000'
                        },
                        select: {
                            fill: '#0000FF'
                        }
                    }    
                },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yTRxZ/5/

By setting select state you will get color changed after click on button. You also need to call setState() for that button. Take a look at the example

Comment: Thanks a lot, Vasi. I managed to get that working thanks to your help. I added in code to highlight the linear button on load and to de-highlight the non-active button.
https://jsfiddle.net/gL3c6xpm/4/